# Newton's Second Law Questions

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

The total mass is 2300kg (weight = 5072lbs). Find the size of the force due to wind and rolling friction when the van speed is 44.86mph (1mph= 0.447m/s).

[image]

I am really at a loss of what to do here.

Part 2:

How much net power, in hp (1 hp=746W) must the engine deliver to maintain a speed of 44.86mph (20.05m/s) (Neglect losses involved in delivering the power).

Comment: Are you meant to calculate the acceleration from the graph?

Comment: no... Bad tag, I fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the graphed data, the acceleration appears constant and I estimate it at $$ a = \frac{40-55}{25-5} = -0.75 \text{ mph/s} = -0.33528 \text{ m / (s$^2$)}$$
You know the mass is 2300 kg, so you can just plug in to get the force of friction using
$$ F = ma $$

As for the power, I believe (please check this) that in your 1D case, the power is given as $P = Fv$ where $v$ is the velocity.

Comment: Please don't post complete answers to homework-like questions in the future, as mentioned in our [homework policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714).